# org.hibernate.Query .iterate() VS .getResultList() query generation

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql

I am using `org.hibernate.Query` Api to query for result. But i ran into strange problem.
This is suppose my query `select DISTINCT abc FROM ABC abc where ORDER BY abc.name ASC`.

I have tested this with `Oracle database`.

let say i have code as below

```
public static List executeQuery(EntityManager em, Query query) {
        org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class);

        // this piece of code is used to fetch data from cache based on id
        if(EntityCacheable){

        Iterator<Entity> it = hibernateQuery.iterate();
        return "";
        }else{

        //This finnaly return the result
            return query.getResultList();
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is for the above query, `hibernateQuery.iterate()` generates query like below

`select abc.id FROM ABC abc where ORDER BY abc.name ASC`, which is not valid. Since what you have in `order by clause` should be there in `select clause` also.

But `query.getResultList()` generates something as below,

`select abc.id, abc.name FROM ABC abc where ORDER BY abc.name ASC` -- so i am safe here

I can make changes in my query and proceed further, but is this an issue in `Hibernate API` or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seems to be an issue with `Hibernate API`, infact this the desired behaviour.

**Query.iterate()**:

Return the query results as an `Iterator`. If the query contains multiple results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of `Object[]`.`Entities` returned as results are initialized on demand. The first SQL query returns `identifiers` only.

Executes `1+N SQL` queries. The first query only returns the identifier of all the records and when the returned iterator is iterated then each time a separate SQL query is executed that contains a WHERE clause like `WHERE id=N`. If the records are present in cache then the first query is executed and the rest N queries are not executed and records are obtained from cache.

```
Iterator<Employee> iterator1 = session.createQuery("from Employee").iterate(); // SELECT EMP_ID FROM EMP
while(iterator1.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator1.next()); // SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMP_ID=?
}
Iterator<Employee> iterator2 = session.createQuery("from Employee").iterate(); // SELECT EMP_ID FROM EMP
while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator2.next()); // From cache, no SQL
}
```

**Query.getResultList()**: `Executes 1 SQL query` and loads the entire data. Even if the records are present in cache a fresh SQL query is executed to load the records from the database.

```
List<Employee> list1 = session.createQuery("from Employee").list(); // SELECT *FROM EMP
for (Employee e : list1) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
List<Employee> list2 = session.createQuery("from Employee").list(); // SELECT *FROM EMP
for (Employee e : list2) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```