# Hibernate query.list()

Tags: java, hibernate, list

I have a query which collects data from an Oracle database.  The results it sends is put in a list in the following way:

```
List resultsList = query.list();
int count = Tools.getSizeList(resultsList);
```

The getSizeList is below:

```
 public static int getSizeList(List l) {
    int r = 0;

    if (l != null) {
        r = l.size();
    }

    return r;
}
```

However for a particular query, this throws an exception.  I have ran the query in the database and this returns no result.  The code I am analyzing, for some reason, cannot be run on my PC.  So there is no way to debug it to know exactly why I am getting an exception.  Is there any way to know why the code above would give an exception?  Cause even if the query returns no result, the list would be empty.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267054/org-hibernate-query-iterate-vs-getresultlist-query-generation) might help

Comment: Please specify the code throwing an exception and what exception

Comment: This code is valid. It can't be a reason of the error.

Comment: @SandeepSukhija:  I can't tell you these as the code is not running on my PC.

Comment: @v.ladynev:  It must be because this is where the code crashes and sends an exception.  I know this from the log.

Comment: @tabby But I don't know from the log. Please, add the log.

Comment: @v.ladynev:  I think the error comes from the query itself.  If the query is wrong, it would return a null value. Hence the query.list() will throw an exception.  Am I right?

Comment: @tabby No. If `query.list()` throws an exception, it goes up of the call stack until it will be catched.

Comment: @v.ladynev:  That's what I meant.  Sorry.  So if the query is wrong, query.list() will throw an exception which will be catched later on.

Comment: @tabby Yes. And it should be logged an added to your question.